# ajaxForm doesn't create html element

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

What's wrong with my script.
it doesn't create an html element on ajax success?

**Here's the script :**

```
$('.ajaxForm').ajaxForm({
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data){
            if(data.msg=='ok'){
                setTimeout("fnChangePage('/login')",5000);
            }else{
                $(".dialog p").html(data.msg);
                $(".dialog").dialog({
                   title : "Error!"
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

**my json's output is like this :**

```
{"msg":"&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Repeat Password!&lt;\/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Employee not found!&lt;\/li&gt;&lt;\/ul&gt;"}
```

[image: Here's the image for reference]

Comment: What error you get in the console.log?

Comment: @jQuerybeast, no error.. it just outputs just like this
<ul><li>Repeat Password!</li></ul>

Comment: Do console.log(data.msg) before you append that to the html and see what you get. You are not giving enough information and neither from where you retrieve the data. Try making a jsfiddle if possible in order we can help you

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the following line is the one that you want to create an html element:

```
$(".dialog p").html(data.msg);
```

Then you need `data.msg` to contain that element *including the html tags*. So you'll need to change your server-side code to output `<` and `>` instead of `&lt;` and `&gt;`. That is, your JSON output should be:

```
{"msg":"<ul><li>Repeat Password!</li><li>Employee not found!</li></ul>"}
```

If you can't make the change server-side for some reason you could replace it in JS before using it:

```
$(".dialog p").html( data.msg.replace(/&gt;/g,">").replace(/&lt;/g,"<") );
```

Comment: is there anyway that I can use htmlentities, to prevent XSS ?

Comment: Why do you think XSS is a potential problem here?